# expo-crypto not returning same hash as node crypto module

Tags: hash, cryptography, expo

I'm working with the Node crypto library in my web application and expo-crypto in my app. I need to have the same functionality in both. The value from the Node crypto library is correct but for some reason I'm getting another value with expo-crypto.

Currently the web solution is working as expected.

```
const randomData = 'XTXpQWATVzlHSp2ZjvmoAfvXYDtT3O1q4SYFIDyPXardJhiLbC/tiw==';
const hashedValue = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(randomData).digest('hex');
```

The hashed value above is `932ed33fb9688dce41620b2a835d353598d410f76fdc0de34b057393443cffcb3733360cf18327df66d8dc120f94dd1c28741f81b098f8dee26c1a0b0a37d4e1`

My expo app solution is not returning the same value as the web solution:

```
import Crypto from 'expo-crypto'
const randomData = 'XTXpQWATVzlHSp2ZjvmoAfvXYDtT3O1q4SYFIDyPXardJhiLbC/tiw==';
const hashedValue = await Crypto.digestStringAsync(Crypto.CryptoDigestAlgorithm.SHA512, randomData);
```

This hashed value, from `expo-crypto` is `270a2e3a3ea41fca841611e2dc539ac6110a9d64cc68cc16165e25020b1c3cec36d3d1680009e999c8f934a2926f0e12be1a1bd6664235cc08da02809028b10c`

Ideally they would both return the same value, any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'node crypto library'? The value you show for expo (270a...) is the correct hash of that value, and I get that correct value (not 932e...) from the builtin 'crypto' in nodejs 12,14,16,18 and commandline openssl, and also from `require('crypto-js').SHA512('...').toString()` (4.1.1 in npm).

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I'm referring to https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html. 

To elaborate a bit further. I need my backend and frontend hashing to sync up. My backend is in python, using hashlib to generate the hash. And the python hashing returns `932ed...`

Comment: That is indeed the nodejs builtin, and your first code, with `const crypto=require('crypto')` and `console.log(hashedValue)` added, on all versions of nodejs I have handy, gives me the 270a... value (and so does the other software I listed). What nodejs are you running that code on? If the python is producing 932e..., it's wrong; can you show the python code, and identify the version?

Comment: `932e...` results when `XTXp...` is Base64 decoded before hashing with SHA-512.